# [iOS Objective c]-How to get all thread information

Tags: multithreading, get, stack, trace

I just wonder to get all thread information.
Is there any way to get about that?
For example when one app got the crash then show the all thread's stack trace on Xcode. 
I want to get that information with objective-C code.
Please help me.
Thank you!